# Jackson java. @JacksonInject dont work while using it's with @JsonDesirializier

Tags: java, jackson

I have class Student with builder nested, and `@JacksonInject` on one field

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Student.Builder.class)
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    
    @JacksonInject
    private int id;
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final double score;
    private final boolean olympicGamer;

    
    private Student(String name, int age, double score, boolean olympicGamer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.score = score;
        this.olympicGamer = olympicGamer;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public boolean isOlympicGamer() {
        return olympicGamer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Student student = (Student) o;
        return age == student.age &&
                olympicGamer == student.olympicGamer &&
                Objects.equals(name, student.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, age, olympicGamer);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", score=" + score +
                ", olympicGamer=" + olympicGamer +
                '}';
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "set")
    public static class Builder  {

        
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private double score;
        private boolean olympicGamer;

        private Builder() {}

        public Builder setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setScore(double score) {
            this.score = score;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setOlympicGamer(boolean olympicGamer) {
            this.olympicGamer = olympicGamer;
            return this;
        }

        public static Builder create() {
            return new Builder();
        }

        public Student build() {
            return new Student(name,age,score,olympicGamer);
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try to inject value to field with `@JacksonInject` it's just dont work

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            int counter = 1;
            InjectableValues inject = new InjectableValues.Std().addValue(int.class,counter);
            Student student = mapper.reader(inject).
                    forType(Student.class).
                    readValue(request.getInputStream());
            try(IStudentDao dao = new StudentDao()) {
                dao.create(student);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new  RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

`Student` is created but value of field `id` is always 0. When i'm dont use `@JsonDesirializier` and `@JsonPojoBuilder` and use `@JsonCreator` (with `@JsonProperties`) it's work. Question is why it's dont work while using `@JsonDesirializier`?